# c# mysql - Searchbox. search specified

Tags: c#, mysql

Good Day. i am working on my searchbox. How do i search from multiple columns. Aside from "id" column, I have firstname, lastname, RFIDnum. How would I add them to my current code.

This is my code :

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dbdataset);
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("convert(id, 'System.String') LIKE '%{0}%'", searchbox.Text);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding other conditions too along with an OR operator like,

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dbdataset);
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("convert(id, 'System.String') LIKE '%{0}%' OR convert(firstname, 'System.String') LIKE '%{0}%' OR convert(lastname, 'System.String') LIKE '%{0}%' OR convert(RFIDnum, 'System.String') LIKE '%{0}%'", searchbox.Text);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it says "Cannot find column [firstname]."

Comment: what is the name of the column in your dataview for firstname?

Comment: it goes something like this: select id as 'ID', RFIDnum as 'RFID NUMBER',firstname as ' FIRST NAME',lastname as 'LAST NAME'

Comment: id column is INT. the rest is varchar